# How to disable swagger 3 configuration in spring boot

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-3.0

I have a requirement to support swagger 2 & 3 in my spring boot API.

I have created swagger 2 using docket object & for swagger 3 just added maven dependency `springdoc-openapi-ui`. Able to check swagger 2 & 3 documentation.

how do I disable/enable only swagger 3 or swagger 2? I mean how do I disable swagger 3 configurations?

I don't have swagger 3 configuration class to enable/disable by using `@profile`. Just adding `springdoc-openapi-ui` maven dependency swagger 3 worked.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the answer copied from this [comment](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/18#issuecomment-520280867)

> The following property is available since: v1.1.16
>
> **springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false** This property helps you disable
> springdoc-openapi endpoints.
>
> If you want to expose the api-docs endpoints without using the
> swagger-ui, you can use the core dependency:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.16</version>
</dependency>
```